# Search for words and insert a comment next to each word

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a Power Point presentation. The legal department sent a file with a list of words to avoid, and for each word a recommendation/comment.

I need to be able to search this words and insert next to each of them a comment with the recommendation/comment.

I've been able to do this in Word, but I cannot make it work in Power Point. Any idea? Thanks!

I've tried this, but didn't work. (**I have to be honest, I don't know VBA. The one I did for Word was based on multiple answers form this site.**)

```
Sub Legales_ES_PPT()

For Each sld In Application.ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
        If shp.HasTextFrame Then
            Set txtRng = shp.TextFrame.TextRange
            Set foundText = txtRng.Find(FindWhat:=Acceture, MatchCase:=False, WholeWords:=True)
            Do While Not (foundText Is Nothing)
                With foundText
                    .Comments , "Usar Preferentemente: Relación / vínculo / formar un equipo / acompañar estr­atégicamente. Aclaraciones: MMZ: una asociación es una figura legal que implica compartir ganancias."
                End With
            Loop
        End If
    Next
Next
MsgBox "¡Listo!"
End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some code to show you made an attempt, and we can debug that.

Comment: Adam, I just edited the post.

Comment: Please do not use the exact phrase "it didn't work". That's quite obvious because if it did, you probably would not have asked here. Help us to help you. Tell us what happened: computer exploded, PowerPoint exited, you got an error message? (If the latter: *what* error?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a rough version to start with; it'll only find the first instance of the search text in each shape. To find all instances, you'll need something a bit more complicated, and you will NOT want to use the loop as in your original version; it'll never end because unless you replace the search text with something else, it'll keep finding the search text.

```
Sub Legales_ES_PPT()

Dim sld As Slide
Dim shp As Shape
Dim txtRng As TextRange
Dim foundText As TextRange

For Each sld In Application.ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
        If shp.HasTextFrame Then
            If shp.TextFrame.HasText Then
                Set txtRng = shp.TextFrame.TextRange
                Set foundText = txtRng.Find(FindWhat:="Text", MatchCase:=False, WholeWords:=True)
                If Not (foundText Is Nothing) Then
                    sld.Comments.Add foundText.BoundLeft, foundText.BoundTop, "Author Name", "AN", _
                        "Usar Preferentemente: Relación / vínculo / formar un equipo / acompañar estr­atégicamente. Aclaraciones: MMZ: una asociación es una figura legal que implica compartir ganancias."
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next
MsgBox "¡Listo!"
End Sub
```